# Django: Cache-Control: max-age. How to specify? What is cached?

Tags: django, caching, http-headers

I'm making a webpage and ideally I'd like the user's browser to cache all javascript, css, and images forever (or the max allowed 1 year). These items are either versioned or they do not change. However, I do not want the html to be cached.

I'm confused about Cache-Control: max-age. Do I set this for each type of resource (css, js, etc)? Or once for everything? Or for specific files? Will it cache the html?

I'm using Django. Where would I even specify it:

```
return render_to_response(my_template, {},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I've noticed that my browser (I've tried several) caches images and js even though I have not specified anything. But can I depend on this always? And for how long will it be cached?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this header on individual static files. However you *should not* be serving static files from Django in production. Use a web server such as Nginx, Lighttpd for that, or better yet, a CDN.

Comment: It also includes user uploaded images. I would like for these to be cached and they will be served from django. And, still, where do I set the header for an individual file. In the html? In my code?

Comment: You shouldn't serve uploaded images from Django either. So the answer is still the same: set this up in the web server configuration (or use a CDN in which case it will be most likely be automatic)

But just for clarity, if you serve a file from Django (don't do that!) the header would be set in the view that serves the file. If you are using the built-in view function you won't have control over that. In order to be able to set headers, you'd need to explicitly write your own view that serves static files and set the header in it. However, that would be really inefficient.

Comment: Does CDN support user-based access (using django's session framework)? I want so serve files to users but do not want to make an entire folder readable to all users (limited knowledge of Apache and django integration here).

Are you saying it is inefficient as in slow file serving, or a waste of time to program? What is the overhead for a django view anyway? Isn't the python code compiled to .pyc at first run? Thanks.

Comment: @FizxMike Various CDNs support various authentication mechanisms, though I don't think any of them would work with Django's auth package out of the box - you'll have to write some glue code.

Comment: @FizxMike By inefficient I meant latency, throughput and memory usage. Whether the benefits provided by using a CDN are worth the effort really depends on your use case. If you just need to serve something like avatar you can probably do that with Django. But if you have lots of files or large files (e.g. video) that require authentication you better dig deeper into the matter.